# First steps in sbt

Tags: jvm, sbt, startup, scalac

I just wanted to avoid slow JVM start up and cleanup in the `scalac <some file>` and `run <some class>` loop. That is, I asked for an environment that can be loaded once and then compile and run my app multiple times. At #scala channel, I got a recommendation to use `sbt`.

I once used ready-made sbt script during #progfun course but never programmed sbt myself. It looks like a hell. How do you easily configure it for my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% mkdir myproj 
% cd myproj 
% echo 'object MyProject extends App { println("hello world") }' > MyProject.scala
% sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/tisue/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to myproj (in build file:/Users/tisue/myproj/)
> set scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
[info] Defining *:scalaVersion
[info] The new value will be used by *:Additional arguments for the presentation compiler., *:allDependencies and 13 others.
[info]  Run `last` for details.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to myproj (in build file:/Users/tisue/myproj/)
> session save
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to myproj (in build file:/Users/tisue/myproj/)
> run
[info] Updating {file:/Users/tisue/myproj/}myproj...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/tisue/myproj/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Running MyProject 
hello world
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed Nov 18, 2015 9:46:26 PM
>
```

if you want you can put your sources under `src/main/scala` instead of at the root level of the project directory — that works too.

`session save` creates a `build.sbt` file that looks like:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
```

you can add more settings there later if you like, either with `set` and `session save`, or by editing the file directly.

if you don't set `scalaVersion` explicitly, sadly you'll get Scala 2.10 instead of 2.11 :-(

Comment: a good blog post on this is http://tpolecat.github.io/2014/12/12/getting-started.html

Comment: Surprisingly, nowhere we specified the main class. I have discovered that `run-main MyProject` does the trick and I think that it is worth to be a part of `Getting Started`.

Comment: I had to use `set includeFilter in (Compile, unmanagedSources) := "*.scala" || "*.sc"` to include worksheet files into compilation.